# Can we install CDH4 on new Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

Can any one share the steps to follow in installing CDH4 on UBUNTU  14.04 version.

Comment: cloudera.com makes no mention of 14.04 but they do mention Precise which was 12.04.  Suggest you email their support to verify compatiblity.

Answer (score 2):

CDH (current version 5.0.3) is not currently supported with Ubuntu 14.04.
However, you can try

1. manual installation method
2. this blog [here](http://blog.datoin.com/2014/06/how-to-setup-cloudera-5x-and-hadoop-on.html)
3. adding the repos for CDH for ubuntu 12 to your ubuntu 14 and installing using apt-get

Your Mileage May Vary

I could never get the Cloudera Manager to get it working, but have installed CDH components manually with great success using point 3 above.